# Circular Array Queue

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, queue, circular-buffer

Im trying to implement a circular array queue without a count variable.

Im looking for a way to determine if the array is full, for it to call the expand method but it doesn't seem to be working any idea why? Thanks!

```
public void enqueue (T element) {
        if(front != (rear+1) % queue.length) {
            queue[rear] = element;
            rear = (rear+1) % queue.length;
        }
        else
            expandCapacity();
    }

public void expandCapacity() {
        T[] larger = ((T[]) (new Object[queue.length * 2]));

        for (int scan=0; scan < queue.length; scan++) {
            larger[scan] = queue[front];
            front = (front+1) % queue.length;
        }
        front = 0;
        rear = queue.length;
        queue = larger;
    }
```

Comment: small part of a project im working on yes, but i'm having problem implementing the queue.

Comment: So whar are initial values of front and rear and how queue.length works?

Comment: initial values of front and rear are zero, queue.length = size of the array im using

Comment: When you say "it doesn't seem to be working", exactly what is the problem?

Comment: if the input file is larger than the array it does not expand

Comment: it doenst make much sense to me to have a circuler buffer and expand it when the buffer is full. why make it circular, if you are resizing regardless. you are not saving any space to start with.

Comment: How it "doesn't seem to be working", what test case?

Comment: @DarthVader: Imagine you enqueued/dequeued elements at the same rate such that at any given point, its size does not exceed say 10 elements.  A circular queue could have millions of elements put in it this way without resizing.  How would a non-circular approach handle it?  When you dequeued, would you move all elements up one index?  That's really expensive.

Comment: I've tried this code, and it *does* expand. With exactly the code as written above. With the small modifications i give in my answer, it even expands correctly. See https://gist.github.com/3893650

Comment: @SkipHead: I was limiting this to the assumption that it was array-based to match DarthVader's comment ("why make it circular, if you are resizing regardless...").  Obviously linked lists are a whole different ball game, but they don't use a buffer at all, so I don't think that's what DarthVader was getting at.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://fr.scribd.com/doc/14768610/Array-Circular-Queue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing i see that's wrong is that in the case where you need to expand, you don't ever add anything to the queue! The `enqueue` method needs to look like:

```
public void enqueue(T element) {
    if (front == (rear + 1) % queue.length) {
        expandCapacity();
    }
    queue[rear] = element;
    rear = (rear + 1) % queue.length;
}
```

In addition, in `expandCapacity`, you're setting `rear` to be one larger than you should; make it:

```
    rear = queue.length - 1;
```